# Why does paginating with offset using PSQL make sense?

Tags: postgresql, pagination

I've been looking into pagination (paginate by timestamp) with a PSQL dbms. My approach currently is to build a b+ index to greatly reduce the cost of finding the start of the next chunk. But everywhere I look in tutorials and on NPM modules like express-paginate (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-paginate), people seem to get chunks using offset one way or the other or fetching all the data anyways but simply sending them in chunks which to me doesn't seem to be a complete optimization that pagination is for.

I can see that they're still making an optimization by lazy loading and streaming the chunks (thus saving bandwidth and any download/processing time on the client-side), but since offset on psql still requires scanning previous rows. In the worst case where a user wants to view all the data, doesn't this approach have a very high server cost since if you have per say n chunks, you're accessing the first chunk n times, the second chunk n-1 times, the third chunk n-2 times, etc. I understand that this is really in terms of IOs so it's not that expensive but it still bothers me?

Am I missing something very obvious here? I feel like I am because there seems to be a lot more established and experienced engineers who seem to be using this approach. I'm guessing there is some part of the equation or mechanism that I'm just missing from my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you understand this quite well.

The reason why so many people and tools still advocate pagination with `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` (or `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`, to use the standard's language) is that they don't know a lot about databases.  It is easy to understand `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` even if you the word “index” to you has no other meaning than ”the last pages in a book”.

There is another reason: to implement key set pagination, you must have an `ORDER BY` clause in your query, that `ORDER BY` clause has to contain a unique column, and you have to create an index that supports that ordering.

Moreover, your database has to be able to handle conditions like

```
... WHERE (name, id) > ('last_found', 42)
```

and support a multi-column index scan for them.

Since many tools strive to support several database systems, they are likely to go for the simple but inefficient method that works with every query on most database systems.